# Weex "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: apt, 20.04, permissions, updates, segmentation-fault

I have installed: WEEX by `apt install weex` on Ubuntu 20.04

When I try to use this program I get error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` on Ubuntu 20.04

But If I install this on Debian 10, Its working fine,

I want solve the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` the problem for Ubuntu 20.04
Because I can't change OS;

How I can solve? Should I import WEEX from Debian repo or other solution.

URL: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/weex.1.html

weex -V

`Fast Webpage Exchanger Ver 2.8.0 Copyright (C) 1999-2000 Yuuki NINOMIYA`

which weex

`/usr/bin/weex`

apt-cache policy weex

```
  Installed: 2.8.3ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.8.3ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.3ubuntu2 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status



linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9e534000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fba20623000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fba20a36000)
```

I try to sync local dir to remote dir. I have done full sync with rsync.

but rsync take time to recheck dirs for deleted files and added new files from local dir.

I want to use WEEX, and don't want to delete exiting files which is already uploaded to remote dir
and then I want configure WEXX, If I delete or add files, I don't recheck full.

Comment: Can't reproduce on fresh 20.04 LTS VM. What is the output of `weex -V ; which weex; ldd $(which weex); apt-cache policy weex` - please add it to question.

Comment: Hi, @N0rbert Question Updated thnx

Comment: Please write your question in more reproducible way to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Can you run `ubuntu-bug weex` on the report and file a bug report for the version of weex in the repository?  Include error output, etc. you get because that's important for developers and such to find the broken packages and get fixes loaded up

Answer (score 1):

as I tested WEEX on Debian, and It was working fine.

So I install it from Debian and it solved my problem.

remove Ubuntu WEEX:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove weex
```

And Install:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/weex/weex_2.8.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i weex_2.8.3_amd64.deb
```